# SVG filter "pipeline": IN and RESULT - default values

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I have a question re this snippet below (taken from MDN). So the filter below has 2 filter primitives feFlood and feBlend that are in this sequence exactly. Why would we need to still set attribute "result" for feFlood and such result is used by feBlend that follows it immediately?
And in the same way - why would we need to use "in2" attribute in feBlend if the result we are using is just from the previous filter?

Generally speaking I am interested to learn if it is ok to omit those provided we control the order in which filter primitives are in the code.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <filter id="spotlight">
      <feFlood result="floodFill" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"
          flood-color="green" flood-opacity="1"/>
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="floodFill" mode="multiply"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <image xlink:href="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
      x="10%" y="10%" width="80%" height="80%"
      style="filter:url(#spotlight);"/>
</svg>

<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <filter id="spotlight">
      <feFlood x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"
          flood-color="green" flood-opacity="1"/>
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" mode="multiply"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <image xlink:href="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
      x="10%" y="10%" width="80%" height="80%"
      style="filter:url(#spotlight);"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#FilterPrimitiveInAttribute)

> If no value is provided (for in) and this is the first filter primitive, then this filter primitive will use SourceGraphic as its input. If no value is provided and this is a subsequent filter primitive, then this filter primitive will use the result from the previous filter primitive as its input.

The SVG specification is somewhat unclear on the matter of the in2 attribute.

Comment: Hey Robert, I know you are very experienced with the SVG filters topic so from your experience - is it better to always list those attributes even if code works without those then? The context of my question is that I have a code that builds html templates dynamically (angular, builts filters' xml templates) and I wanted to see if I should always by default create these attributes from data objects that in my case describe filters.

Comment: It's not necessary but it's much easier to debug filters if you have explicit results and ins. There are many filters where you want to reference a previous intermediate result, not the immediately preceding primitive.